# Eclipse reference to class from non-class

Tags: java, eclipse

Suppose we have a class (some `ScreenBean`) that is referred only from a configuration file (e.g. `struts.xml`)

If we right click such a class in Eclipse, Reference -> Workspace doesn't find anything (obviously, there are no references from other Java classes).

Is there a way to 'learn' Eclipse to scan plain-text ( config files etc ) for references to java classes (to avoid situation when a developer thinks there is no usage for the class and deletes it)?
For sure if the developer uses full-text search himself he'll find the usage but it would be cool to have support from IDE

Comment: There might be some support for the major tools (Spring for example) but all config/XML files have different format and semantics, it wouldn't be feasable to do a generic solution for that. There might be some plugins though that may help you with textual search & matching for example, but I'm not aware of such a tool.